# Converting string to char array and then back into string

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

I am using Protobuf to change data between computers with sockets. To transfer the data I'm using the following:

```cpp
myProtoMessage::Message m;
string s;
m.SerializeToString(&s);
const char *msg = s.c_str();
// Send msg through socket
```

However, I noted that Protobuf can't read any of the received data that isn't of type int (it assigns it to 0).
Sure enough, if I don't use the socket but try to get my message back in the same snippet of code the same occurs:

```cpp
myProtoMessage::Message m;
string s;
m.SerializeToString(&s);
const char *msg = s.c_str();
myProtoMessage::Message m2;
m.ParseFromString(msg); // my data is lost
```

I also noted that:

```cpp
myProtoMessage::Message m;
string s;
m.SerializeToString(&s);
const char *msg = s.c_str();
string(msg) == s; // 0
// Let's try it again
string s2;
int size_msg = sizeof(msg) / sizeof(char);
s2.assign(msg, size_msg);
s2 == s; // still 0
myProtoMessage::Message m2;
m.ParseFromString(s2); // the data is lost
```

So, why is that I can't correctly convert data back to string? If it's a question of refence, why can't protobuf read the char array data or the string data converted from the char array?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

### Edit

A better example of my code:
Protobuf message (message.proto)

```proto
syntax = 'proto3';

package message;

message Message1{
    uint64 time_us = 1;
    uint32 id = 2;
}
message Message2{
    uint64 id= 1;

    double l1= 2;
    double l2 = 3;
    float l3 = 4;

    enum MyEnum {
        IDLE = 0;
    }
    MyEnum myEnum = 8;
}

message CompleteMessage{
    Message1 message1 = 1;

    Message2 message2 = 2;
}
```

My code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "message.pb.h"
#include "boost/asio.hpp"

using namespace boost::asio;

using namespace std;

// Send data through socker
void send_message(const char* msg, int msg_size, const char* IP, int port)
{
  io_service io_service;
  ip::udp::socket socket(io_service);
  ip::udp::endpoint remote_endpoint;

  socket.open(ip::udp::v4());

  remote_endpoint = ip::udp::endpoint(ip::address::from_string(IP), port);

  boost::system::error_code err;
  socket.send_to(buffer(msg, msg_size), remote_endpoint, 0, err);

  socket.close();
}

// Fill message data
void fill_m1_data(message::Message1* msg, uint64_t time_us, uint32_t id)
{
  msg->set_id(id);
  msg->set_time_us(time_us);
}

// Fill message data
void fill_m2_data(message::Message2* msg, uint64_t loaded_mission_id,
                     double latitude, double longitude, float altitude, 
                     message::Message2::MyEnum state)
{
  msg->set_id(loaded_mission_id);
  msg->set_l1(latitude);
  msg->set_l2(longitude);
  msg->set_l3(altitude);
  msg->set_myEnum (state);  
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
  message::CompleteMessage m;
  fill_m1_data(m.mutable_message1(), 1, 1);
  fill_m2_data(m.mutable_message2(), 1, 22.0, 42.0, 10.f,                          
  message::Message2::MyEnum::MyEnum_IDLE);

  // Convert protobuf data to string
  string s;
  m.SerializeToString(&s);
  const char *msg = s.c_str();
  
  // Check the data, everything is fine
  cout << "message 2" << endl;
  cout << m.message2().id() << endl;
  cout << m.message2().l1() << endl;
  cout << m.message2().l2() << endl;
  cout << m.message2().l3() << endl;
  cout << m.message2().myEnum() << endl;
  cout << "message 1" << endl;
  cout << m.message1().id() << endl;
  cout << m.message1().time_us() << endl;

  // Get back the data
  message::CompleteMessage m2;
  m2.ParseFromString(msg); // get data back
  // converting msg back to string by the methods above yields the same results
  cout << "message 2" << endl;
  cout << m.message2().id() << endl;
  cout << m.message2().l1() << endl; // 0, should be 22.0
  cout << m.message2().l2() << endl; // 0, should be 42.0
  cout << m.message2().l3() << endl; // 0, should be 10.0f
  cout << m.message2().myEnum() << endl;
  cout << "message 1" << endl;
  cout << m.message1().id() << endl;
  cout << m.message1().time_us() << endl;

  // Send the message
  send_message(msg, s.length() - 1, "192.168.0.0", 9000);
  
  return 0;
}
```

Protobuf documentation: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/cpptutorial

### Edit 2

The following code works when sending and receiving data through a socket:

```cpp
// send
string s;
msg.SerializeToString(&s);
void *buffer = malloc(s.size());
msg.SerializeToArray(buffer, s.size());
send(fd, buffer, s.size(), 0);
free(buffer);
// receive
numbytes = recv(connectfd, buf, MAXDATASIZE, 0);
buf[numbytes] = '\0';
// Receive  msg from clients
message::CompleteMessage m;
m.ParsePartialFromArray(buf, sizeof(buf) / sizeof(char)); // sizeof(buf) / sizeof(char) can be changed to numbytes
```

Not the cleanest, but does the job. The question about the string and char array persists though.

Comment: I don't understand the `const char*` usage, and `sizeof(msg)/sizeof(char)` is definitely wrong. Can you provide a [mcve], referencing the documentation on how to use ProtoBuf messages with strings?

Comment: what is `mv`? ..

Comment: @JohnFilleau, mv was a typo, it is supposed to be m.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings I will edit the question with a example.

Comment: Check the return values of your serialize and deserialize function calls. All required fields must be set in the message for serialization to work.

Comment: Protobuf throws an error if it can't serialize/deserialize. Still, I don't get why converting a string to a char array and then back to string yields different result (they are not equal if you compare the original string to the one recovered from the char array).

Comment: You are effectively truncating the serialized representation at the first zero byte, since you treat the buffer as a NUL-terminated string. Serialization of a protobuf may very well contain zero bytes. I predict that, after `m.SerializeToString(&s)` call, `s.size() != strlen(s.c_str())`

Comment: I see. How could I convert a string to a char array while preserving the 0 bytes? Would a loop suffice?

Comment: Take a step back. Why exactly do you want to traffic in raw `char*`? What's wrong with `std::string`? It holds a array of `char`s as well as its length, and can handle embedded zeros just fine. Just pass `string`s around, don't attempt to convert to `char*` and back - it makes no sense, and won't work. E.g. `m.SerializeToString(&s); m2.ParseFromString(s);` should work, and preserve all original data.

Comment: I didn't know that a string could be passed through a socket with cpp. I only found examples using char arrays, and the server will read it as a char array anyway. I already managed to pass the message using another protobuf method, but I'm still curious about the string to char conversion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string serialized from a protobuf message is a binary string. You cannot construct a `std::string` with a single binary char pointer. Instead, you should also specify the size of the binary string.

```
myProtoMessage::Message m;
string s;
m.SerializeToString(&s);
const char *msg = s.c_str();
myProtoMessage::Message m2;

// in this case, msg will be converted to std::string,
// and will be truncated when it meets the first '\0'.
// That's why your data is lost
// m.ParseFromString(msg); // my data is lost

// Instead, you should call `ParseFromArray` to specify the size of the string buffer.
m.ParseFromArray(msg, s.size());

// Or construct a std::string manually.
m.ParseFromString(std::string(msg, s.size()));
```

```
myProtoMessage::Message m;
string s;
m.SerializeToString(&s);
const char *msg = s.c_str();
// Send msg through socket

// When you send msg, also specify the size of the message:
// send(sock, msg, s.size(), flags);
```